# Can i dynamically Render HTML Elements in Razor using a passed in string variable

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a C# MVC Web App.

My Model passes in a value and type and in my UI Razor I handle it like this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i != Model.SectionModel.Count; i++)
{
    <div style="clear: left; padding-left: 20px;">
        @Html.Label(Model.SectionModel[i].Name)
        <div class="clear"></div>
        @for (int j = 0; j != Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel.Count; j++)
        {
            switch (Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Type)
            {
                case "radio":
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m=> m.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Default)
                    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Default, Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name)
                    break;
                case "text":
                    @Html.TextBox( Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Name,Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Default)

                    break;
                default:
                    <div>test dud</div>        
                    break;
            }
             <div class="clear"></div>
        }
    </div>
}
</div>
```

But to support more than these 2 HTML Elements and not to use a 'switch' discriminator I was wondering whether I could do this by 'writing' the control like so:

```
@Html.WriteAControl(Model.SectionModel[i].PreferenceModel[j].Type)
```

Obviously, `@Html.WriteAControl` is SUDO code...

Comment: Sure you can create your own control. Like this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91c28d/custom-html-user-control-in-Asp-Net-mvc-razor-view-engine/

Comment: @MoshFeu Hi thanks for edit and link. Good of you.This is C# solution and relies on CSS.  I was hoping for a Razor solution and no CSS but use the 'native' controls.